# Take off file path (home/user/file.txt = file.txt)?

Tags: java, file, text, path

So I've written a simple text editor in java, and it retrieves the file via `showOpenDialog()` and converts the filename into a string, so it can be displayed as the title:

```
        String title = fc.getSelectedFile().toString();
```

But lets say I have the path "home/user/file.txt". How would I strip off the path and make it so the filename displays as "file.txt" only?

Comment: @home: While you *can* do that, it's not the best approach.

Comment: @Jon Skeet: you're right. I did not realize that `getSelectedFile()` returns a `java.util.File`, removed the comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

File [getName()](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/File.html#getName%28%29) returns what you want i.e just the last name in the pathname's name sequence.

Comment: I think this is the best way.

Answer (score 1):

`getSelectedFile()` returns a `File` object; the easiest thing to do would be to just call `getName()` on the `File` object. If the path comes from someplace else, you could actually construct a `File` from it and *then* call `getName()`.

Answer (score 0):

```
String filename = title.substring(title.lastIndexOf("/"))
```

edit: brain's answer is better and more concise though :-)

Comment: I wouldn't do this unless I was sure that I was on a Unix-like platform. And even then I'd prefer to use java.io.File